# How to Get JSON Object Within JSON Array

Tags: json, android-studio

i want to get **avatar_url** in **actor** object. i can get **"id"** and **"type"** to show in recyclerview. but avatar_url not show image why?

[json url](https://api.github.com/events)

```
final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

           try {
               for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                   Article article = new Article();
                   article.setAvatar_url(jsonObject.getString("avatar_url"));
                   article.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                   article.setType(jsonObject.getString("type"));
                   articles.add(article);
```

how i get **avatar_url** from **actor** field?

[image]

> and yes i can run because i delete
>   article.setAvatar_url(jsonObject.getString("avatar_url"));

**Thanks**

Comment: It would be helpful to look at how you are binding the data to the UI and the UI code as well.

Comment: Improve your question to make it easier to answer: Remove the screen cap, it doesn't add any value. Showing the top bit of the JSON would explain your problem and make the answer obvious.

A clear statement of the question might be: I can retrieve the "id" and "type" but get this error <msg> when trying to get the "avatar_url"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JSON, you can see that the "avatar_url" isn't a peer of the "id" and "type".

```
"id": "11392115556",
"type": "PushEvent",
"actor": {
  "id": 8517910,
  "login": "LombiqBot",
  "display_login": "LombiqBot",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/LombiqBot",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/8517910?"
},
```

You need to retrieve the "actor" object and then get the "avatar_url" from within that object.